# Including multiple schemas in SQLDatabase.from_uri method in langchain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I've been attempting to include multiple schemas in the SQLDatabase.from_uri method in LangChain, but so far, none of my attempts have been successful.

Method 1:

```
db= SQLDatabase.from_uri(
    odbc_str, #db connection string
    schema="schema1,schema2",
    #include_tables=['schema1.tableA', 'schema2.tableB', 'schema2.tableC'],
    view_support=True
)
sql_toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=llm)
sql_toolkit.get_tools()
```

Method 2:

```
db1= SQLDatabase.from_uri(
    odbc_str, #db connection string
    schema="schema1",
    #include_tables=['tableA'],
    view_support=True
)
db2= SQLDatabase.from_uri(
    odbc_str, #db connection string
    schema="schema2",
    #include_tables=['tableB','tableC'],
    view_support=True
)
sql_toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=[db1, db2], llm=llm)
sql_toolkit.get_tools()

sqldb_agent = create_sql_agent(
    llm=llm,
    toolkit=sql_toolkit,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    verbose=True,
    handle_parsing_errors=True,
    view_support=True

)
```

I have also tried including only the database in SQLDatabase.from_uri method in the hope that the SQL agent I build on this identifies all schemas it owns, but maybe I was too ambitious with my approach. The SQL toolkit doesn't seems to work that way. The agent returns empty set when asked to list all the tables.

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Action: sql_db_list_tables
Action Input: ""
Observation: 
Thought:I have obtained a list of tables in the database. Now I can query the schema of the relevant tables.
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? Or any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you:

In the given context, an individual has crafted a subclass of the SQLDatabase to provide support for managing multiple schemas.

https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/3036#issuecomment-1602004448